# Git rebase keeping all features branch (assume their are no real conflicts)

Tags: git

I have `master` and `feature` branches.  I simply want to rebase `master` into `feature` .. I'm already sure that any changes or conflicts should auto resolve to use `feature` (no one is editing those files and I did don't have any feature changes in master)..

This has worked for me in the past:

```
git checkout master
git pull
git checkout feature
git rebase master
git rebase --skip
git rebase --skip # until the REBASE N/M is done
git pull
```

Again, I know I'm not stepping on any edits from master, we work on separate files.  Basically this worked once.  I have since made more commits to `feature` and tried it again.  Everything worked the same except the last step `git pull`..

Turns out `git pull` left me with lots of CONFLICT files all having to do with my own changes and all auto-resolvable (just keep the feature branch already!)...

If I start from scratch (`git reset --hard origin/feature`) then instead run `git merge master` I end up with what appears to be about the same number of CONFLICT files (lot of them with many changes within).  I would rather keep the HEAD and ignore the master part of the conflict.  It would take 20 minutes to edit all those files by hand and I have to repeat anytime I need to update my feature branch..

How do I resolve these conflicts (or avoid them) without editing every file and fixing every conflict?

I'm not sure how to avoid the mess, one way to manage it easily is as follows: Use the `git merge` keep a script of commands like the following while being aware of any commits that might cause more complex conflicts:

```
function git-resolve-by-branch() {
    git checkout ${1?branch} ${2?file} && git add ${2?file}
}
```

Comment: It seems that `get merge` just avoids all the `--skips` but still leaves me with a tone of conflicts.

Comment: I just have to copy a few files and methods to a new branch as a work-around.  Still would be nice to understand this better, I would like to get more advanced on our use of branches.

Comment: __pull__ is just a shorthand for __fetch__ _and_ __merge__

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A rebase is best done on the same branch, as from which the feature branch was created. As what a rebase actually does is:

- stash the changes you made
- update your feature branch, as if it just was create
- apply you changes, on the *new* branch

**The image top shows**

- A checkout, with creating a branch *feature*
- Then you make changes *a* and *b* to the *feature* branch
- Then a fetch is done, and a change *c* is coming in

**Lower part**

- The rebase is complete, showing the change *c*, from *master*, and the original changes *a* and *b* as if the just where made

[image]

So if a rebase is done on a different branch, then all changes of the feature branch are transfered to the new feater branch. This can be very tricky, as the branch, from which the rebase is done, can be quite different, then the original branch, used to create the feature branch.

**When to Merge**

Development takes place on a feature branch. Each time new commits, are done on the *master* branch, they can be safely added to the *feature* branch, by appling *rebase*.
Once development is done on the *feature* branch, switch to the *master* branch, and *merge* the feature branch, back into master.

Comment: So far my actions follow your plan.  I have been rebasing on the feature branch and I have yet to merge (but that is certainly what I will do when the time comes, thanks).  The issue states with something I'm doing to trigger conflicts.  I'm not even editing the same code at the same time but I get conflicts between different commits on the same parts of the code.  I'll prob accept your answer and provide a more specific example when I can narrow this down better.  Thank you!

Comment: Maybe describe better when files are changed, on which branch. I do not understand the `git rebase --skip` you show in the example. Also the final `git pull` is unclear. As it tell to git to _fetch_ and _merge_ master into feature. But you just did some rebasing! You should __only__ do rebase on that branch, never a _merge_. Then all you commits on the branch _feature_ are at the front of that branch. Then switch to the branch _master_ and do a merge from _feature_. So all your commit from _feature_ are merged into _master_.